# create parquet file with Clickhouse and read with DuckDB

Tags: clickhouse, duckdb

Following this guide https://clickhouse.com/docs/knowledgebase/mysql-to-parquet-csv-json I've exported from a MySQL server some tables to parquet.

But I'm not able to read these parquet files with DuckDB.

I can inspect the structure:

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM 'mytable.parquet';
```

but if I try to read:

```
select ID from mytable.parquet;
Error: Invalid Error: Unsupported compression codec "7". Supported options are uncompressed, gzip, snappy or zstd
```

I guess that clickhouse is writing LZ4 compressed parquet files, and duckdb doesn't support them.
Can I change the compression format in clickhouse-local?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change Parquet compression method in ClickHouse, use setting `output_format_parquet_compression_method` (see all Parquet settings in https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/formats#parquet-format-settings).

For example:

```
select ... format Parquet settings output_format_parquet_compression_method='snappy'
```

Answer (score 1):

--output_format_parquet_compression_method                                       Compression method for Parquet output format. Supported codecs: snappy, lz4, brotli, zstd, gzip, none (uncompressed)

try `output_format_parquet_compression_method='snappy'`

```
clickhouse-client -q "select * from numbers(1e6)  settings
 output_format_parquet_compression_method='snappy' format Parquet " > test.parquet
```